# cron job in php

Tags: cron, php

I wrote cron job as below:

```
#11 01 * * * /var/www/mail.php
```

php code

```
<?php
#!/usr/bin/php
$to = "test@test.com";
$subject = "php mail";
$message = "Hi this is simple message.";
$from = "example@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

I am trying to set cron job by calling a php file for sending mail.But I didn't not any solution. Please help me.

Comment: is your site hosted on web? o0r in local folder

Comment: Have you tried executing it directly?  Have you tried executing it by calling PHP?  Have you tried octern's suggestion and put the shebang line at the top?  Have you tested the `mail()` command in a script you know actually runs?  How broken is your exim or sendmail config?  What's in your spam folder?  Did you packet sniff on the server to see that the mail is being sent?

Comment: Is your PHP executable actually in /usr/bin/php?

Answer (score 7):

First of all, your shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/php`) needs to be _before_ the opening PHP tag (and before any other lines or characters as well).

If it still doesn't work after that, try adding some debugging output with error_log() and check your error log to see if the script is running at all. If the script isn't starting at all, there's still a problem with your cron job. If it is, you can proceed to debug the PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you have +755 permisions for you file

```
01 * * * * /usr/bin/php php /var/www/your_path/update.php
```

Replace php with php5 from usr/bin path if your folder is php5

Comment: How could you possibly know what's on the OP's path, or even what operating system he/she is running?!  How about fixing the obvious problems, before introducing new ones?